# Add rows to Google Sheets sheet if not enough

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a bunch of data that I routinely use a Python script to back up into a Google Sheets sheet. It's currently at 5385 rows filled with 6041 total. I know that if I try to upload more than 6041 rows the update will fail, but I know that I can fix this by opening up the sheet, scrolling all the way to the bottom, and then clicking "All 1000 more rows at bottom" a few times.

Is there a way for `googleapiclient` to automatically make sure that there's room in the sheet?

Edit:

```
        cells = 'Backup!A{}:{}{}'.format(start_ind, self._excel_column_index(len(headers)), start_ind + len(to_cache) + 1)
       
        values = self._excel_serialize_arb_array(to_cache, headers)
        data = {'values':values}
        self.sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_ids['FOO'],
                        range=cells, valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
                        body=data).execute()
```

Comment: Please provide the code you''re currently using to add to the existing sheet. That being said, can't you just append the new data at the bottom as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values)? IIRC it should add new rows if needed...

Comment: @EdoAkse I added some of the code I'm using. I was just using update, but if there's a way to rewrite this with a thing that fixes the issue that would be great.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `I know that if I try to upload more than 6041 rows the update will fail`? Because in the case of `values().update()` method, when the length of inserted values are over the maximum row of the current sheet, the new rows are automatically inserted. So I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike: I expected that to be true, but when it actually happened my program crashed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I expected that to be true, but when it actually happened my program crashed.`, I cannot still understand your situation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution coded up.

```
def get_and_update_sheet_properties(self, min_rows):
    ''' Ensure we have enough rows for our arbs cache. '''
    sized_sheets = self.sheet.get(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_ids['FOO'],
                                  fields="sheets(properties(title,gridProperties(columnCount,rowCount)))").execute()
    arb_sheet = [sized_sheet for sized_sheet in sized_sheets['sheets'] if sized_sheet['properties']['title'] == 'BAR'][0]
    cur_rows = arb_sheet['properties']['gridProperties']['rowCount']
    padded_rows = min_rows - (min_rows % 100) + 200
    if padded_rows > cur_rows:
        requests = {
                "updateSheetProperties": {
                    "properties": {
                        "sheetId": 1922941665,
                        'gridProperties': {
                          'rowCount': padded_rows,
                          'columnCount': 26
                        },
                    },
                    "fields": "gridProperties",
                }
            }
        body = {
            'requests': requests
        }
        self.sheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_ids['FOO'], body=body).execute()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you for the update on how you implemented the option to edit the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to update the properties of the Sheet itself or create a sheet with the properties of more than 1000 rows.

Note: I build the code over apps script before your edit with your code.

```js
/**
 * Add a new sheet with some properties.
 * @param {string} yourspreadsheetId The spreadsheet ID.
 */
// This funcion would add a sheet with 10,000 rows that would be empty and that they can be filled

function addSheet() {
   const spreadsheetId = "yourspreeadsheetID"; 

  var requests = [{
    'addSheet': {
      'properties': {
        'title': 'Deposits',
        'gridProperties': {
          'rowCount': 100000,
          'columnCount': 2
        },
        'tabColor': {
          'red': 1.0,
          'green': 0.3,
          'blue': 0.4
        }
      }
    }
  }];

  var response =
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, spreadsheetId);
  Logger.log('Created sheet with ID: ' +
      response.replies[0].addSheet.properties.sheetId);
}

// This function is to write all 10,000 rows bypassing the 1000 limit that you might be having 

function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "yourspreadsheetID"; 
  //  Spreadsheet ID.
  const max = 10000;
  const data = [];



  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    data.push({range: `Deposits!A${i + 1}`, values: [[`A${i + 1}`]]});
  }
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({data: data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"}, spreadsheetId);
}
```

I run the first function to create the Sheet with the properties using the "batchUpdate" and was able to add 10,000 strings to it.

I would assume that on Python you need to increase the number of rows in the sheet using an UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest or InsertDimensionRequest check it here: [Sheet API update properties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)!

Comment: I'm thinking that https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest might be the answer.

Comment: Correct, my code was only an example that you can use the batchUpdate to modify properties of the Sheet to add more rows even without having any data onto them or going to the web. Which is why I mentioned that particular link were I got the reference. Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay, I just got it to update the gridProperties. Is there a way to find out what gridProperties are before updating them? With that I will accept this answer.

Comment: Turns out I can find that with `self.sheet.get(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_ids['FOO'], fields="sheets(properties(title,gridProperties(columnCount,rowCount)))").execute()`